# algorithm for ranking items with multiple dependencies

Tags: algorithm, sorting, statistics, ranking

I have an entity which depends on 5 variables x[1] to x[5] , The more the value of the variable the higher the chance of getting selected , Now given multiple entities i need to rank them so that the top entity has the most chance of getting selected . Can u please suggest me an algorithm to solve this.
Also the variables might not have the same weight and i need to decide the weight given to each variable using an algorithm.
currently I am just multiplying each variable and sorting accordingly

Comment: Unclear. Why not provide sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: My input will be multiple entities which will have 5 values for example E1(1,2,3,4,5) and E2(2,3,5,4,1) now i want to come up with an formula which would help me rank them

Comment: for example suppose you just simply take the rms value (sqrt(x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+x4^2+x5^2)) each variable then both the above entities will get the same score but if I say that the variable x2 will affect the chances of getting selected more so I might want to add some extra weight to my formula (sqrt(x1^2+(w*x2)^2+x3^2+x4^2+x5^2)) so that the entity with higher x2 will get more preference

Comment: I need to analyse some pattern and come up with a formula which would give each entity a score on the basis of which I can rank my Data